# How to Sync Messsages Between Android and MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages

I'm having a difficult time getting texts to show up on the Messages app on my laptop and my Android phone. It's really weird because some texts appear on my phone while others get sent to the Messages app. When I sent a message to myself via phone, it didn't get sent to the messaging app, but every once in a while someone will send me a text that gets routed to my laptop and not my phone.

Not sure whether is a problem with my phone, service or the compatibility of Messages with Android. Is my only recourse to delete Messages on Mac? I'd hate to do that without knowing that all my messages would be redirected to the phone. FYI my Android version is 4.4.4 and I have the latest OS installed on Macbook Pro.

Comment: Do the message that show up on the Mac NOT show up on your Android phone? Messages, by default sends to/from Apple devices using iCloud. You have to explicitly set up messages to get SMS (I believe...)

Comment: second that.
Messages allows for exchanging messages among users of the IOS/OSX ecosystem AND to receive and send SMS via a iPhone mobile line. There is no way to have an Android phone to have its SMS messages to show in Messages on OSX

Comment: Most messages received on Messages also show up on my phone. When setting up messages, it didn't say I needed an IOS ecosystem. It just linked up my iCloud account and accepted my phone number.

Comment: @st4rgut It's not intended to work that way. Try [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com)

Comment: @st4rgut, strange because Messages usually accepts (and prompts to accept) only those phone numbers that it detects from a iPhone where the same iCloud user is registered....